# Problem with nested CSS calc, sqrt and pow functions returning 0

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a div to draw a line from one point to another in pure HTML/CSS without the use of js or svg.
(I know this is a bit stupid, but Im trying to make something that will work in mediawiki and that doesnt support inline svg...)

I have everything working except the correct height of the div (the length of the line). As the line can have an arbitrary start- and end-point and therefore also an arbitrary angle, I am trying to calculate the required length in CSS via pythagoras.
I have the coordinates for the start and the end of the line as css variables (start point: --x1 / --z1, end point: --x2 / --z2), so I can calculate the horizontal distance and the vertical distance and thus two legs of a right triangle. The hypothenuse of this right triangle would be the line I want to draw (obv) and therefore have the length I need.
I am now trying to calculate that length in CSS like this:

```
height: calc(1px * sqrt(calc(pow(calc(var(--x2) - var(--x1)), 2) + pow(calc(var(--z2) - var(--z1)), 2))));
--x1: 20; --z1: 20; --x2: 35; --z2: 50;
```

The variables are meant in px, but do not have a unit in them. I am testing with x1: 20, z1: 20, x2: 35, z2: 50. 
That should return a value of around 33px for height, but it doesnt. It just sets the height to 0px.
I have double and triple checked the formula, even put it in some online CSS validators, which all tell me that this is a perfectly valid CSS formula and should work. Firefox inspector also doesnt indicate any errors or problems of any kind with this formula, it just apparently somehow gets to a result of 0 when calculating this.

FYI: I know there are probably one or two unnecessary calc()'s in there. I added those when it wasnt working and I was trying to figure out why it wasnt working. Afaik I should not need the calc()'s inside the pow() or inside the sqrt(), but I wanted to make sure that that wasnt causing a problem.

At this point I am at a loss as to why this is not working properly.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Edit: Here is my entire test html doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #outerCont {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .line {
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(1px * calc(var(--x1) - var(--startX)));
      top: calc(1px * calc(var(--z1) - var(--startZ)));
      width: 5px;
      height: calc(1px * sqrt(calc(pow(calc(var(--x2) - var(--x1)), 2) + pow(calc(var(--z2) - var(--z1)), 2))));
      transform: rotate(atan(calc(var(--x1) - var(--x2)) / calc(var(--z2) - var(--z1))));
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outerCont" style="--startX: 0; --startZ: 0">
    <div class="line" style="--x1: 20; --z1: 20; --x2: 35; --z2: 50;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using firefox.

As for why I am using z for the y axis, thats simply because it will make sense in the final application.

Comment: Aside: Just curious, why do you use "z" in your naming convention for the y axis.

Comment: I do not get height 0 from this - it seems to work fine - so please include a runnable snippet which you have tested definitely shows the problem.

Comment: what browser are you using? sqrt() and pow() are still new

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dbts2xw0/ gives me the same looking result in both Firefox and a Chromium-based browser. And when I check on the calculated/computed height of the `.line` element, I am getting `33.5333px` in FF, and `33.5391px` in Chromium.

Comment: The code given works fine on FF for me (Windows10).

Comment: "in mediawiki and that doesnt support inline svg" ... so likely it doesn't support a lot of other features

Comment: That is somewhat true @GetSet, but almost everything css can be done via templatestyles. Mediawiki currently does not support inline svg, though it does support displaying of .svg files (if enabled). Javascript is not allowed on wiki pages or templates at all, which is why Im trying to do css only.